# Addition v/s elimination with double bond and OH together

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, c-c-addition

> If a compound has both an hydroxyl group and a double bond and we add $\ce{HBr}$ to it,
>
> (**a**) substitution reaction to the hydroxyl group can take place, or
>
> (**b**) an addition reaction of a double bond can happen.

How to decide which one will occur?

What kind of conditions favour which type? Eg : How are the products affected by different conditions like solvent medium , Temperature, Structure , etc

Comment: Which is more likely to protonate first, the hydroxyl group or the double bond?

Comment: @Waylander I don't know..., I read organic from a book , and these were in 2 different sections...

Comment: It is important to specific the context. Is it dry HBr gas or aqueous HBr? Is it carried out at high temperature or is the reaction done at room temperature?

Comment: @TanYongBoon Actually , I have read about these 2 reactions in different sections of a book. There was no combined form given. But in my tests , these questions will surely be asked. Can you please tell me how would the different conditions like Temp/Solvent affect the reaction. I would be really grateful. Thank You

Comment: In almost all conditions the hydroxy group will protonate first. You then need to consdier whether an external or internal nucleophile is more likely to react with it.